# How could Intent be null in onHandleIntent()?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

My android app crashes and this is the logcat :-

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMBaseIntentService.java:194)
    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

I looked into android gcm r3 source and I found that
the argument intent is null in onHandleIntent().

Is this even possible? How to fix it?

(I know null intent could be seen with `Service.onStartCopmmand` returning `START_STICKY`
  but `IntentService.onStartCommand` doesn't use `START_STICKY`.)

Comment: How can you say that the intent is null?? Focus on line 194 in your onHandleIntent(), there might be somthing else which is getting null...

Comment: Thank you for reply.
Because I have the jar and source from android sdk. line 194 is
"String action = intent.getAction();"

Comment: The intent is null on some systems and it is totally normal in case msg.obj that gets passed is null. There is no null check there.

Comment: Consider adding your voice to this bug report https://code.google.com/p/gcm/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=20

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntentService's onHandleIntent(Intent) gets null argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309582/intentservices-onhandleintentintent-gets-null-argument)

Answer (score 1):

I think application crashes only in some devices during installation time. It's because during installation GCM service also receives some `Intent` from other Google source and your broadcast receiver is not prepared to handle this type of `Intent`.

If you just want to receive GCM Intent which you want to pull from server through push notification, then just use this in your handle Intent call.

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        //String msg = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        String from=extras.getString("from");
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {

            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                sendErrorNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                sendErrorNotification("Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString());
                // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i + 1) + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                // Post notification of received message.
                // sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
                /*********ERROR IN SOME DEVICES*****************/

                 if(from.equals("google.com/iid"))
                 {
                     //related to google ... DO NOT PERFORM ANY ACTION
                 }
                 else { 
                   //HANDLE THE RECEIVED NOTIFICATION
                     String msg = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                     sendNotification(msg);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
                     }
                 /**************************/
            }
        }
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}
```

Comment: I agree, my GCMBroadcastReceiver receives some null intent from time to time, so I have to check if the incoming intent is null or not. I don't know what happens, but I get a null intent during installation.

Comment: Any update on this how to solve and check this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Happend to me once, I was passing wrong URI. Reference the documnetation for the intent u wanna pass.

[Intent Documentation here.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)